# How to merge two for loops as on for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have the following script. I would like to combine the two for loops into one loop. How do I do that?

```
for index, row df.iterrows():
    for tag in df.tag.unique()):
        print(row)
        print(tag)
```

Comment: Start by providing a sample of data and the expected output. Also, is your goal really to print all combinations of rows and tags? or do you want to perform a calculation? `iterrows` should be avoided

Comment: @Mayank I have the feeling that the issue is something else ;)

Comment: @mozway Let's wait for OP to explain the issue. Will reopen if it's something else, otherwise better keep it closed ;)

Comment: @Mayank I was about to vote to close for lack of details ;)